# jQuery Redis hit counter to track view of cached Rails pages

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, redis

I have static cached pages that I want to track the hits of and then order by popularity.

What would be the best way of tracking these views in Redis and then loading them back into the main database?

Right now I am thinking of using jquery like this

```
$.get("/track/", { id: "1234" } );
```

and using the redis gem in a "track" controller to call

```
redis.incr "1234"
```

Once a day I would then run a cron to of something like

```
Pages.each do |p|
   p.hits = redis.get(p.id.to_s)
end
```

Comment: Quick comment: your $.get should really be a $.post action since it's making a change on the server rather than getting something.

Comment: GET might be better for reducing the overhead, since POST generates 2 requests with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @supo why would post generate 2 requests?  That's not supposed to happen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my final rake task, just in case it helps anyone

```
require 'redis'
task :cron => :environment do
   uri = URI.parse(REDIS_URL)
   REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)

   Pages.all.each do |p|
      views = REDIS.get(p.id.to_s)
      if views
          p.hits = p.hits + views.to_i

          if p.save
             REDIS.set pId, "0"
          end
       end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

What your doing is a good way to do it, but you can also use the server log to get the number of hits on that page. Using the server log would allow you do not have to add code to each page, and would enable to track unique hits, not just hits. IF you are keen on doing it with Redis, then your way is good.

Comment: Thanks, after trying to parse the log (difficult on heroku) and trying  a rack solution (not working with cacheing), I think I am sticking with Redis