# Transactional Create with Validation in ServiceStack Redis Client

Tags: redis, servicestack

User has DisplayName and it is unique for Users.

I want to Create User but firstly I have to check display name (DisplayName could not be duplicated for Users)

I've checked ServiceStack examples and I could not see Transactional Insert/Update with  validation check.

How can I perform it. I dont want to write "Validation Tasks" for redis db.
I dont want inconsistency in db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/) client does have support for Redis's [WATCH](http://redis.io/commands/watch) and [transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) where these Redis commands:

```
WATCH mykey
test = EXIST mykey
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

Can be accomplished with:

```
var redis = new RedisClient();
redis.Watch("mykey");
if (!redis.ContainsKey("mykey")) return;

using (var trans = redis.CreateTransaction()) {
    trans.QueueCommand(r => r.Set("mykey", "val"));
    trans.Commit();
}
```

Comment: The Requirement is checking Keys "in" transaction but It is done before transaction in your sample. As a sample https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/RedisAuthRepository.cs .  AssertNoExistingUser and Store operations must be transactional in CreateUserAuth method.

Comment: RedisAuthRepository can store two new users with same displayname.

Comment: Read up on Redis Transactions (http://redis.io/topics/transactions) the WATCH affects the next subsequent transaction. i.e. if any of the **watched keys** were modified in-between the WATCH command and the transaction, the transaction doesn't get executed and an exception is thrown.

Comment: I 've never seen "Watch" style implemantation for 12 years .. I could  not guess . Thanks a lot. RedisAuthRepository is still vulnerable for race condition. But I will implement and share it.  Best regards.

Comment: How can we suggest code refactor or fix for ServiceStack project @mythz?

Comment: Best way is to send a pull-request with tests :)

Comment: On the 3rd line of this example, should the code call `UnWatch()` before it returns?

Answer (score 2):

Is possible to perform redis transactions. More information [here](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)

```
WATCH mykey
test = EXIST mykey
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

Using PHP have um better example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291333/calling-redis-get-inside-a-loop-to-display-forum-post-view-data)

Comment: I don't mean Multiple Insert or Multiple Delete. I mean CheckIfNotExists option.

Comment: I think my question is more related with http://redis.io/commands/eval. But I'm tryinh to find solution with ServiceStack Redis client.

Comment: what redis client you are using?

Comment: do not know ServiceStack Redis Client, but read [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisTransaction) documentation exist a second parameter 'Action onSuccessCallback'. I think that solve.

Comment: It will be complicated. "If you have a relational databases background, the fact that Redis commands can fail during a transaction, but still Redis will execute the rest of the transaction instead of rolling back, may look odd to you. [http://redis.io/topics/transactions]" I need Existance Check like your sample code. But thanks for your answers.