# Autoincrement Id with transaction in Redis (ServiceStack RedisClient)

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

ActionSuccess callback with IncrementKey  does not work in transaction:

```
public class Article
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void Can_create_article_with_autoincremental-id()
{
    Article a = new Article() { Name = "I Love Writing Test" };
    using (var trans = Redis.CreateTransaction())
    {
        trans.QueueCommand(r => r.IncrementValue("id:article"), id => a.Id = id);
        trans.QueueCommand(r => r.Store<Article>(a));

        trans.Commit();
    }

    Assert.That(Redis.Get<Article>("1").Id,Is.Equal("1"));
}
```

Comment: Only ask 1 question per question. If there's an issue with the client submit a failing test.

Comment: When actionsuccess callback be executed? If after transaction commit, there is no solution for it.

Comment: Submit a failing test at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis - if you want someone to look into your problems.

Comment: https://github.com/glikoz/ServiceStack.Redis/commit/d0e15bfe37b72932fe72edebb809c05aafa28f26

Comment: I'm using VS.Net UnitTesting framework. So writing test, converting your test to Vs.Net for debugging is so painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis transactions are all executed at the same time where callbacks only fire after the entire transaction has been completed. So you cannot use the return values in the callbacks within the same transaction in another part of that transaction.

If you just wanted to store an Article with an autoincrementing Id counter, you can simply do:

```
var a = new Article { 
   Id = Redis.As<Article>().GetNextSequence(), 
   Name = "I Love Writing Test" 
};
Redis.Store(a);
```

There's no need for the transaction for this. To use values from Redis inside a transaction which will only execute if none of the values have changed use the [WATCH](http://redis.io/commands/watch) command. See my earlier answer [for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844575/85785).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid unnecessary increments and empty ids. Because if there will be cancellation (I'm using WATCH also).  Article's id will be useless.

Comment: So maybe real question is: how can i guarantee sequential id in Redis?

Comment: Yes. But If your transaction fails (transaction is executed after GetNextSequence()) your object could not be stored to db.    1) GetNextSequence 2)WAIT for unique index 3) Open transaction (can fail because of wait- (unique index-race condition)) 4) If transaction fails you have id Hole in Db.

Comment: a) There is no transaction above. b) just retry failed transactions using same id.

Comment: I've added gist could you check db after operation https://gist.github.com/2882459 I've tried to demonstrate race condition.

Comment: Well normally you would just re-try the transaction, but since you're doing the exact same call 100 times there's not much point. Note at the time the transaction fails you have the unused id - so you can add it to a re-use pool or handle it however you wish.

Comment: Yes I made race condition test. It means "what's happen when two different user try to insert same unique field?" . Answer is "unused-id" .

Comment: I'm planning to use redis-db for all persistance requirements (not only cache or analytics). I hope I'm on the right road :)